# Z axis in slick2D

Tags: java, slick

Firstly, I'm very new to slick2d, java, and coding in general, so if I apologise for any very obvious or basic errors that I've made.

I'm developing a JRPG type thing in slick 2d and the battle system revolves around players and enemies moving around a 7x4 grid, being able to move one space each turn before their normal action. I'm having problems getting different sprites to render in a set order so that an illusion of a three dimensional space is created, with sprites on the bottom row of the grid rendering above sprites in the second row, which in turn renders above the third row and so on.

I've found a few different sources on this website and others saying that the best way is to sort the characters by their y axis position and render them in that order, I've got as far as creating variables for each characters y axis position, put them into an array and made an algorithm that sorts them from lowest to highest, ie. from sprites I'd like to render at the bottom to sprites that should be rendered on the top. I can't figure out how to actually use this sorted array to draw the sprites in the correct order though.

Someone in another thread said:

"Sort the array based on the Y of those objects, from lower to higher. Now when you draw these objects, draw them from 0 to array.length, objects with low value will be drawn first, then objects with higher value will be drawn on top of them."

but I don't know how to draw them from 0 to array.length. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Edit:

for drawing the characters so far I just have:

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
    Backdrop.draw(0,0);
    Grid.draw(0,0);

    P3Stance.draw(p3x, p3y);
    P2Stance.draw(p2x, p2y);
    if(Helmeton) {
            P1Stance.draw(p1x, p1y);
        }
    if(Helmetoff) {
            P1StanceU.draw(p1x, p1y);
        }
    }

    Hud.draw(0,0);
```

the x and y values of the characters are just set to static values for now.

For the array and the sorting I have:

```
float[] zarr = new float[8];
```

and in my update method:

```
    zarr[0] = p1y;
    zarr[1] = p2y;
    zarr[2] = p3y;
    zarr[3] = p4y;
    zarr[4] = e1y;
    zarr[5] = e2y;
    zarr[6] = e3y;
    zarr[7] = e4y;

    int n = zarr.length;  
    float temp = 0;  
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){  
        for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
            if(zarr[j-1] > zarr[j]){  
                temp = zarr[j-1];  
                zarr[j-1] = zarr[j];  
                zarr[j] = temp;  
                }           
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly identified that sorting the y positions on their own will not help you draw things in the right order. What you need to do is bundle together the data needed to draw a character, and sort those bundles, then draw the bundles in that order. If it helps you can think of playing cards with the characters' pictures and x and y positions on them. We need to sort the stack of cards by the y position and then look at cards of the stack one by one and draw them.

It looks like you have your character data in separate variables right now, so you'll need to collect them together into bundles so we can sort them. The way data is usually bundled together in Java is with Objects. So  let's make a character object.
(I have not used slick2D in particular so I'm guessing that `P2Stance` and `P3Stance` are instances of something called a `Stance`. If that guess is not correct you'll have to correct this code slightly.)

```java
public class Character {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public Stance stance;

    Character(float x, float y, Stance stance) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.stance = stance;
    }
}
```

The above code defines a class of Objects called `Character`. So now you can make new `Character`s with `new` like so:

```java
    Character p3 = new Character(p3x, p3y, P3Stance);
    Character p2 = new Character(p2x, p2y, P2Stance);
```

And then you should be able to draw them like this:

```java
    p3.stance.draw(p3.x, p3.y);
    p2.stance.draw(p2.x, p2.y);
```

Now you have some special logic for the first player character so we need to handle that case in particular. There are multiple ways to deal with that. The best way depends on the how many characters have helmets. From the code you've shown I can only assume that only the first character will have a helmet. If that is the case, the way that requires the fewest other changes would be to do the check when you make the character object.

```java
   Character p1;
   if(Helmeton) {
        p1 = new Character(p1x, p1y, P1Stance);
   } else {
        p1 = new Character(p1x, p1y, P1StanceU);
   }
```

I'm assuming here that `Helmeton` is always `true` when `Helmetoff` is `false` and vice-versa. In that case `Helmetoff` is unnecessary. if you need to do something only when the helmet is off then you can use `!Helmeton`, where `!` means "not" so `!Helmeton` is `true` when `Helmeton` is `false`.

Now that things are bundled you can put the **characters** in an array and sort them by their y positions. Following the way you did it with the floats:

```java
    Character[] charactersArray = new Character[8];

    charactersArray[0] = p1y;
    charactersArray[1] = p2y;
    charactersArray[2] = p3y;
    charactersArray[3] = p4y;
    charactersArray[4] = e1y;
    charactersArray[5] = e2y;
    charactersArray[6] = e3y;
    charactersArray[7] = e4y;

    int n = charactersArray.length;  
    Character temp = null;  
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){  
        for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
            if(charactersArray[j-1].y > charactersArray[j].y){  
                temp = charactersArray[j-1];  
                charactersArray[j-1] = charactersArray[j];  
                charactersArray[j] = temp;  
            }           
        }  
    }
```

Then you can loop over the `charactersArray` and draw all of the characters, in the proper order:

```
int characterCount = charactersArray.length;
for(int i = 0; i < characterCount; i++){
    Character c = charactersArray[i];
    c.stance.draw(c.x, c.y);
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, not only has this fixed my problem completely but It's also taught me a lot in the process about objects, thanks for the help!

A few small queries though, firstly the Stances were actually just animations, a method imported from slick, but that was easy enough to change as you said, also the values in the array should were coming up with an error, as p1y, p2y, etc. are floats, I changed them to just p1, p2, etc. and they worked fine though. Lastly, am I right in thinking that I would still need to define the variables p1x, p1y, etc. earlier on?

Thanks so much for your help though.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get the animations working. That's right the variables in the array were supposed to be characters, not floats. My mistake, While you can define `p1x`, `p1y`, etc before making the characters you can also pass the number directly into the constructor like this `new Character(200.0, 100.0, /* and so on */)`. One thing to note if you decide to keep them as separate variables for whatever reason: `float` is a primitive type, which in Java means they are copied when they are passed into a method or a constructor. So modifying `p1x` would not change `p1.x`.

Comment: @Ryan1729 I see, so if I add numbers straight into the character constructor rather than use predefined ints and floats, then I'll be able to modify them using p1.x?

Also I tried to give an upvote, but I don't have enough rep to do that yet, I've only had this account for a few days!

Comment: In effect, yes, but what is really happening is that if you use predefined numbers, then when you pass them into the constructor they will be copied so `p1x` and `p1.x` would be different values in memory. So you would be able to change `p1.x` either way, but `p1x` would only change if you changed `p1x` specifically, and vice-versa.

Comment: That makes sense thanks, I'm currently using values like p1x because my game crashes if the characters aren't placed in the update method (one of the core features of slick2d, it runs every frame to update game logic).This means that if I put numbers directly into the character constructor, and then change them, with a button press or something, then they'll just be reset to the original numbers every time the update method calls, so the characters jump back to starting position. I'm not sure why the characters have to be in update method, any ideas?

Comment: I’m not sure why the game crashes. My best guess would be those stance animations being null or some other invalid state. If my guess is correct then you should be able to store characters without animations just fine. But then you would need to find another way to match up characters with animations. One way to test that idea would be to make a new class and try storing it instances of it outside the update method and seeing if the game crashes.